# How to erase empty string from list of strings in Clarion?

Tags: clarion

I'm a beginner at coding in Clarion and I'm coping with problem which can be described as basic.

I have this code:

    `L_COUNTER1 = 2
    LOOP
     IF INSTRING(L_COUNTER2& ';',L_STRING,1,L_COUNTER1 = 0 THEN

                L_LIST[L_COUNTER2] = SUB(L_STRING,2,L_COUNTER1-3) 
                L_STRING = SUB(L_STRING,L_COUNTER1,LEN(L_STRING) - L_COUNTER1 + 1) 
                BREAK
     ELSE
                L_COUNTER1 = L_COUNTER + 1
     END`

Variable Counter1 is part of the outer loop. This code produces me data such

```
L_LIST[1]='test1'
L_LIST[2]='test2'
L_LIST[3]=''(empty)
L_LIST[4]=''(empty)
L_LIST[5]=''(empty)
L_LIST[6]='test3'
L_LIST[7]=''(empty)
L_LIST[8]=''(empty)
L_LIST[9]=''(empty)
```

I'm trying to achieve:

```
L_LIST[1]='test1'
L_LIST[2]='test2'
L_LIST[3]='test3'
```

Or at least

```
L_LIST[1]='test1'
L_LIST[2]='test2'
L_LIST[3]='test3'
L_LIST[4]=''(empty)
L_LIST[5]=''(empty)
L_LIST[6]=''(empty)
L_LIST[7]=''(empty)
L_LIST[8]=''(empty)
L_LIST[9]=''(empty)
```

But I'm stuck on this problem. I tried looping through the elements and checking if they're not equal to empty string but didn't have much success.

Comment: Guessing that you meant:
`IF INSTRING(L_COUNTER2& ';',L_STRING,1,L_COUNTER1) = 0 THEN` 
instead of 
`IF INSTRING(L_COUNTER2& ';',L_STRING,1,L_COUNTER1 = 0 THEN`

Answer (score 0):

Testing the contents should be something like `IF CLIP(L_STRING) > ''` (checks for content in the string) or `IF CLIP(L_STRING) = ''` (check for empty string)

The rest of the solution is to code up a sort for the dimensioned string variable L_LIST. Or use a queue and use `SORT(queue,listfieldname)`

Unless I dont understand the question (or I'm missing some context), there really isnt any need to step through the string a character at a time.